# Azure SSL Offloading on Application Gateway Error

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

Im testing Azure in free-trial and trying to configure SSL offloading through Applcation Gateway via Zure portal.I followed the exact steps in the Azure documents but this gives me below error -

Error: Data must be specified for Certificate

1. I have uploaded proper pfx file.

2.Username same as certificate common name

3.Password is correct pfx password.

Do not understand why it gives error while adding backend pool IP's. Any thing wrong I'm doing.

Comment: can you be more precise? how are you creating the appgw? or how are you uploading the cert?

Comment: Im creating application gateway through portal and uploading the .pfx via portal too.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply. I recreated whole gateway again from scratch and this time it was successful. Azure support person said certificate name was wrong but it was indeed correct.I think it was some network issue which didn't let pfx upload to be successful as I did everything with another network it worked.Also one workaround is to create normal HTTP application gateway and then create new  listeners  and rules separately. This worked fine even multiple times even in the alleged faulty network. So I think this is the best way.

Comment: I'm glad you have solved the issue. I suggest you could write your comments as a reply and mark it as answer, it will help other people who faces the same issue.